# Converting a pandas dataframe to dictionnary of lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, pandas, dictionary

I have the following problem. I have a pandas dataframe that was populated from a *pandas.read_sql*.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
        PERSON              GRADES
20      A                   70
21      A                   23
22      A                   67
23      B                   08
24      B                   06
25      B                   88
26      B                   09
27      C                   40
28      D                   87
29      D                   11
```

And I would need to convert it to a dictionary of lists like this:

```
{'A':[70,23,67], 'B':[08,06,88,09], 'C':[40], 'D':[87,11]}
```

I've tried for 2 hours and now I'm out of ideas. I think I'm missing something very simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `groupby` and `to_dict`

```
df.groupby('PERSON').GRADES.apply(list).to_dict()
Out[286]: {'A': [70, 23, 67], 'B': [8, 6, 88, 9], 'C': [40], 'D': [87, 11]}
```